# Ethereum wallet synced but will not close

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

I am running xtogo gui on ubuntu vps. The blockchain has synced. However, when I try to deploy a contract, the window says that the gas cannot be computed, because the account needs at least 1 eth. The account has 1 eth. So, I need to back out and try something else. However, "quit ethereum wallet" or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> have no affect. I do not want to try `killall` process, as the db may become corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
ps ax | grep Etereum-Wallet
```

Which output:

> 4012 pts/0  S+   0:00 grep --color=auto Ethereum-Wallet

Then I killed it with:

```
pkill Ethereum-Wallet
```

When I restarted with `parity-geth` and then reloaded the Ethereum Wallet, the blockchain was still synced. So, I don't really like this as it takes so long to download the chain. I am still paranoid that the db may become corrupted with this method. I lost the db earlier by shutting down and restarting, so try at your own risk!

Comment: I found later, that the x2go client was failing to show the updated window, that showed the Ethereum Wallet. Upon restarting the client, the window, no longer appeared.